# ¿Como puedo actualizar los datos de mi web tras un UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql

Teniendo este formulario PHP en el que el usuario John lo cambio por ejemplo por Jane (o cualquier otro dato):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
    header("location: error.php");
    exit; 
}

require_once "conn.php";
$conexion=mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die ("Error de conexión:" .
mysqli_connect_error());

$consulta_select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name ='".$_SESSION['name']."'";

$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_select);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modifico los datos, que en la base de datos se hace correctamente, aunque este no se actualizan en la web, si no que tengo que salir de la sesión y loguearme de nuevo. 
En vez de actualizarse, la sesión se queda tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del formulario de modificación:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "conn.php";
$conexion=mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die ("Error de conexión:" .
mysqli_connect_error());

if (isset($_POST['modificar'])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $consulta_update =("UPDATE users SET Name = '$name' , Email = '$email' , Password = '$password' WHERE id = '$id' "); 

    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_update);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
?>
```

Comment: tal vez usando AJAX, o directamente recargando la página una vez que se ha hecho la actualización; para que con un `SELECT` se tomen los datos recientes

Comment: @Aprendiz Miraré lo de AJAX aunque nunca lo use. El formulario obviamente es con un SELECT para sacar la información de la BD, cuando se pulsa sobre "Modificar", va a una página nueva donde si es correcta la información dice Ok, o si no es, pues Error. Pero luego al volver a la web si no salgo de la sesión toda la web esta con la información obsoleta, tengo que volver a logear para que se renueven los cambios hechos al usuario.

Comment: Definitivamente si no quieres recargar la página o volverte a loguear, tienes que usar AJAX.

Comment: @VickMuñoz recargando la pagina no funciona (osea F5 o Ctrl+Shitf+R). Así que sí, tendré que usar AJAX.

Comment: Puedo ver que estás usando $_SESSION para validar el `name` si estás usando esta variable para mostrar, debes actualizar también tu variable $_SESSION['name'] = $name